# Prism 6: Multiple Views get data from one ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

so im working now a week with Prism and it´s great :) my question is now: Can i get the Data from one ViewModel to multiple Views (in most cases 2 Views). I work with the ViewModelLocator like Brian Lagunas in this Webinar -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfBy2nfykqY

The Example from Webinar: I have Views named ViewA + ViewB and ViewModels named ViewAViewModel + ViewBViewModel. Now i want that the Locator take ViewAViewModel for both ViewA and ViewB.

Code ViewA:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MVVM_Prism_Mein_einfaches_Beispiel.Views.ViewA"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVM_Prism_Mein_einfaches_Beispiel.Views"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="lbl_Firstname" Content="Firstname:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="61,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="tb_Firstname" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="129,38,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Label x:Name="lbl_Lastname" Content="Lastname:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="61,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="tb_Lastname" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="129,70,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Label x:Name="lbl_Updated" Content="Updated:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="61,102,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txb_Update" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="129,107,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding LastUpdated}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn_Update" Content="Update" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="129,141,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn_Upview" Content="Update + View" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="129,171,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="ViewTablet"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ViewAViewModel:

```
using MVVM_Prism_Mein_einfaches_Beispiel.Events;
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Events;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using Prism.Regions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MVVM_Prism_Mein_einfaches_Beispiel.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewAViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private string _firstName = "Brian";
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _firstName, value); }
        }

        private string _lastName;
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _lastName; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _lastName, value); }
        }

        private DateTime? _testupdate;
        public DateTime? TestUpdate
        {
            get { return _testupdate; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _testupdate, value); }
        }

        public ICommand UpdateCommand { get; set; }
        private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

        public ViewAViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IRegionManager regionManager)
        {
            _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
            UpdateCommand = new DelegateCommand(Execute, CanExecute).ObservesProperty(() => FirstName).ObservesProperty(() => LastName);

            _regionManager = regionManager;
            NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(Navigate);
        }

        private IRegionManager _regionManager;

        public DelegateCommand<string> NavigateCommand { get; set; }

        private void Navigate(string view)
        {
            _regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", view);
        }

        private bool CanExecute()
        {
            return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FirstName) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LastName);
        }

        private void Execute()
        {
            LastUpdated = DateTime.Now; 
            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<UpdateEvent>().Publish(LastUpdated.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

ViewB should be like ViewA.

Thx for your help. 
Best Regards Shazzar

Comment: Can you post your code to give some context?

Comment: @MichaelDotKnox sry, now it´s in the Question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you're not talking about the same instance, this can easily be done.  You just have to register the ViewModel to the View in the ViewModelLocationProvider.

```
ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<ViewB, ViewAViewModel>();
```

*Note, this specific method is a new feature in the latest preview.  Otherwise, you have to provide a factory instead.

Comment: This looks like a nice feature, when will it be in a stable release?

Comment: In a couple of weeks. So for now you must use the current ViewModelLocationProvider.Register(typeof(ViewB), () => container.Resolve<ViewAViewModel>())

Comment: Looking forward to it, keep up the good work.  Prism in it's current state is an invaluable resource for WPF development.

Comment: After i installed the prism 6.2.0-pre1 it works great with your answer thx :) and i agree with @StephenWilson please keep working i dont want to programm without prism anymore :)